# Rails and SQL, how to .last on all members of a table's associations

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am attempting to form the proper query with limited success so far.

Say I have Users and posts

Users has_many posts and posts belongs to user

posts has a visible boolean field

I am trying to write a scope in the user model that goes through all users, finds their last post, and only returns the user if the value if the visible boolean is true on their last post.

Something like Users.posts.last.where(:visible => true) but in as a scope.

EDIT

I'm trying to keep the return value as an AR relation object, a regular array will not work for what I am trying to use the scope for. Thanks though so far for the input.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this should work.. (non-tested)

```
class User

  def User.users_with_visible_posts
    User.includes(:posts).map {|user| user.posts.last && !!user.posts.last.visible}
  end
end

User.users_with_visible_posts #=> [Users with last post visible]
```

Comment: That went through all of them correctly and indeed could check if the condition was met but that is returning an array value , I'm trying to keep the output as an activerecord relation object

Answer (score 0):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :posts
  scope :last_visable_post, posts.where("visible = ?",true).last
end
```

Comment: That would return the last visible post, i'm looking to return users with who have their last visible post as visible.

Comment: sorry,  (read it too quickly) there is another answer,  just not done as a scope,  you definitely want to use a scope?  I think between the two answers you can figure out how to do it as a scope,  if not I'll take a whack at it.

Comment: Need it as a scope or a class method that returns an AR relation object because I need to perform further queries on the returned results in other areas of the app.

Comment: I really scratched my head on this one I can;t see a way of doing it without resorting to a stored produdure.  .last is an array method,  as soon as you apply it to an AR Relation,  you're stuck with an Active Record instance,  which blows up your attempt to keep it all in AREL and always have AR relations.